# Node.js ask password for secure route

Tags: node.js, express

I have an admin user and I want this user to authenticate before accessing a specific route even though he's currently logged in, for this specific route, I want a password field to appear and the password he enters needs to be valid before he gets redirected to this route, how can I handle this type of middleware? I already have a middleware to check if the user is authenticated, I want to continue checking if he's authenticated and a admin, but I also want the user to re-enter his password before accessing the page, how can I accomplish this?

```
function isAdmin(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        if (req.user.role == 'admin') {
            return next();
        }
        res.redirect('/');
    }
    res.redirect('/login');
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to authenticate a logged in user? p.s, I did not down vote you

Comment: Not authenticate him, but ask for his password to redirect him to route

Comment: @NgugiKariuki Thanks!

Comment: what language are you using for your fron end ? Because I assume you would need to call an interface with the field to confirm the password

Comment: I use ejs templating engine with html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion this is how I would suggest you achieve this:

```js
function isAdmin(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        //one is authenticated
        //check if they are admin
        if (req.user.role == 'admin') {
            //first confirm the password as you want before re-routing
            const confirmPass; //This will be passed from front-end

            //Lets assume you stored your pass in response as password i.e (res.user.password). 
            if((res.user.password)==confirmPass){
            //move out of the function
            return next();
            }

        } else

        //if role is not admin -> Go to homepage
        res.redirect('/');
    }

    //if not authenticated, go to login.
    res.redirect('/login');
}
//next is here-admin
function confirmedAdmin(req,res){
    //code here
}
```